# AngularJs how to hide item-divider which hasn't items

Tags: angularjs, listview, html-lists

How may I hide a `item-divider` which no has list-items when I'm using the filter? This is the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="elem in codeList | orderBy:predicate:reverse">
    <div class="item item-divider">
        {{elem.data}}
    </div>
    <ul class="list">
        <li class="item item-icon-right" ng-repeat="item in elem.array | filter:search" ng-click="action(item)">
            <h2>{{item.text}}</h2>
            <i class="icon ion-{{item.icon}}"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I would like to know how to do it in "Angular way".

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to alias your filtered list with `as filteredItems` (works with Angular 1.3) and use the `filteredItems.length` to conditionally show/hide your `item-divider`.

```
<div ng-show="filteredItems.length" class="item item-divider">
    {{elem.data}}
</div>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="item item-icon-right" 
        ng-repeat="item in elem.array | filter:search as filteredItems" 
        ng-click="action(item)">
        <h2>{{item.text}}</h2>
        <i class="icon ion-{{item.icon}}"></i>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for ng-hide

```
 <div class="item item-divider" ng-hide="elem.array.length == 0">
    {{elem.data}}
</div>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work since `elem.array` could have some items but they all could be filtered out, and thus `elem.array.lengt > 0` but actual list would be empty.

Comment: I'd say `ng-if` is better.

Comment: @NewDev I didn't saw the filter good thinking I guess there is a syntax we can found.

Comment: @Eugene ng-if remove and add to the DOM, while ng-hide set css to make element disapear. I would think that DOM manipulation in a ng-repeat is more costly than hiding it.

Comment: At the same time if it is one time rendering, then DOM is cleaner at the end. But it depends on where ngRepeat is used and will there be a need to render hidden elements later on.

Comment: @NewDev Too bad, actualy I upvoted your answer because I think it's the best ;)